# Spring Boot ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name for @Controller class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I keep getting the `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException` error in my Spring boot application. I am not entirely sure as to how to address it, I have several `@Configuration` annotated classes helping to set up Thymeleaf, Spring Security and Web. Why is the application trying to setup the `homeController` twice? (and where is it trying to do this?)

The error is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Failed to parse configuration class [org.kemri.wellcome.hie.Application]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException:
Annotation-specified bean name 'homeController' for bean class [org.kemri.wellcome.hie.HomeController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [org.kemri.wellcome.hie.controller.HomeController]
```

My spring boot main application initializer:

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

My database config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="org.kemri.wellcome.hie.repositories")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DatabaseConfig {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;

   @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
  }
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory =
        new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    
    // Classpath scanning of @Component, @Service, etc annotated class
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(
        env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.entitymanager.packagesToScan"));
    
    // Vendor adapter
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    
    // Hibernate properties
    Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
    additionalProperties.put(
        "hibernate.dialect", 
        env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect"));
    additionalProperties.put(
        "hibernate.showsql", 
        env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.showsql"));
    additionalProperties.put(
        "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", 
        env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);
    
    return entityManagerFactory;
  }
  @Bean
  public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = 
        new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
        entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }
  @Bean
  public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
  }

}
```

My Thymeleaf config file:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    ServletContextTemplateResolver thymeTemplateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    thymeTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    thymeTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    thymeTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return thymeTemplateResolver;
}   

@Bean
public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect(){
    SpringSecurityDialect dialect = new SpringSecurityDialect();
    return dialect;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();   
    engine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();
    dialects.add(springSecurityDialect());
    engine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);     
    return engine;
}

@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    resolver.setViewClass(ThymeleafTilesView.class);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

}

My Web config class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter  {
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSenderImpl.setHost(env.getProperty("smtp.host"));
        mailSenderImpl.setPort(env.getProperty("smtp.port", Integer.class));
        mailSenderImpl.setProtocol(env.getProperty("smtp.protocol"));
        mailSenderImpl.setUsername(env.getProperty("smtp.username"));
        mailSenderImpl.setPassword(env.getProperty("smtp.password"));
        Properties javaMailProps = new Properties();
        javaMailProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        javaMailProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        mailSenderImpl.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProps);
        return mailSenderImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
    }
}
```

My controller (where there is an error setting up the controller)

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    
    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);
        
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
        
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
        
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

What might be causing the `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException` error for my controller class?

Comment: Try to add **@EnableWebMvc** on your _WebConfig.class_

Comment: That has not worked. I still get the same error.

Comment: mvn clean and rebuild the project .....It worked for me.

Comment: 1) Delete folders: **build** and **out**;  2) Gradle: **clean** and **refresh**.

Comment: A reason may also be a transitive dependency that adds the same bean name in Spring context. The solution is as you already found out - filtering the packages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution, as I found out, is to disable double initialization by including a filter in the component scan. In my case:

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.kemri.wellcome.hie" }, 
    excludeFilters = {@Filter(value = Controller.class, type = FilterType.ANNOTATION)})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you spot exactly the double initialization (except from the stack trace) ? Did you find the cause ?

Answer (score 53):

I ran into the same problem but for a different reason.

This can also occur if you move your classes around in your project and fail to do a 'clean'.

I use gradle with spring-boot plugin. Now I usually run:

```
$> ./gradlew clean bootRun
```

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. The accepted solution helps also, but it is most likely caused by stale data also.

Comment: I'm using Maven. I ran `mvn clean` but still got the error. In Eclipse I ran `Project -> Clean` then the error went away.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem on a Spring integration test **when I ran it with InteliJ**.

After a refactor, one of my controller class was actually duplicate in the */out/production/classes* directory which is the default output directory for Intelij since version 2017.2.
Since the gradle output directory is different (It's *build/classes*), the gradle clean goal had no effect.

**For me the solution was to manually remove */out/production/classes* and re run my integration test.**

For a possible durable solution not having 2 output directories see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174989/building-with-intellij-2017-2-out-directory-duplicates-files-in-build-director)

Comment: you can also check the parameter "Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Runner > Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle"

Comment: It seems (as of 2020.3) that "Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Clear output directory on rebuild" might also provide a solution. Rather than hand-deleting the output, IntelliJ can do it for you.
For what it's worth, I don't have this setting checked and hand-deleting the troublesome subdirectory (not the whole classes folder) worked just fine.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this with mvn after changing several folder names and related package names. Than I applied maven clean and run spring boot again, all solved:

```
mvn clean
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have two entityManagerFactory, one you will autowire and one you resolve programmatically as Bean:

```
@Autowired
private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
...
}
```

I think you just need your configured Factory in entityManagerFactory() method.

Comment: You dont need to override the configure method in your Application Class, because your Class is itself an Application.

Comment: I have removed the configure function in the main application class and I still get the same error.

Comment: Maybe the _entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan()_ and the _@ComponentScan_ annotation does the same job and create the conflict you have.

Answer (score 1):

let's assume your package name - `com.example.company`  and the class name is `RestExceptionHandler`. Then you need to add the full name with the package to be identical.

add annotation `@Component("com.example.company.RestExceptionHandler")`

It will identify your class without conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with a generated .war file from spring-boot. the approved solution (Timothy Tuti's own solution) didn't quite work for me exactly as-is, but I tweaked it a little bit and it worked. I just added the following line to my Application.java:

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.mypackage" })`

For reference, here goes my full Application.java

```
package com.inmoment.devchallenge;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.inmoment.devchallenge.controller" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Configuration
    @EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.inmoment.devchallenge.repository")
    static class ApplicationConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

        public ApplicationConfig() {
            setBasePackage("com.inmoment.devchallenge.repository");
        }

        @Bean
        GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
            return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("accessingdataneo4j.db");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding a bean name on top of the class.

```
@Component("myBeanName1")
public class MyBean {

}
```

And initialize it with **@Autowire** in this way:

```
@Autowire
@Qualifier("myBeanName1")
MyBean myBean;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem when one of dependencies(say module Y) of current module(say X) also had definition of same class. So I had to create a separate module(say Z) to store common classes and then add dependency on Z for both X and Y to use.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to use this gradle task:

**gradle clean build --no-build-cache**

the command is used to perform a clean build of a Spring application using Gradle, ensuring that no build cache is used and all the necessary components are built from scratch.