# IntelliJ Fails Deploying exploded war to tomcat

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a Java web application I am developing in IntelliJ and deploying using Apache Tomcat. I have some run configurations defined that are shared between everyone on the team. These run configurations are defined to deploy an exploded war artifact into a local tomcat. Other team members are able to deploy and run just fine, but I get the following error:

```
Artifact Gradle : project : project.war (exploded): Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
Artifact Gradle : project : project.war (exploded): com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: /IdeaProjects/project/build/libs/exploded/project.war not found for the web module.
```

It seems that IntelliJ doesn't want to create the `exploded/project.war` directories. If I create those directories manually I don't get that error message, but none of the WAR contents get placed into the directory.

I thought that it could be a permission error so I even tried giving my project directory `777` just to try to eliminate possible problems.

Has anyone ever run into this problem?

I am running MacOS 10.12, and have been able to deploy in the past, but this problem just started.

Thanks

**Update**

The IntelliJ log doesn't really show any additional errors, just the full StackTrace for the errors above.

```
2017-11-02 11:20:52,896 [3777157]   INFO - erver.JavaeeServerInstanceImpl - com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: <redacted>/build/libs/exploded/myproject.war not found for the web module. 
com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: <redacted>/build/libs/exploded/myproject.war not found for the web module.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl$DeployStep.perform(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:277)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.doDeploy(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:125)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$4.doPerform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:120)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$JmxOperation.perform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:243)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.doStartDeploy(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:135)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$2.setDeploymentStatus(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:90)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$DeploymentModelOperation.doSetDeploymentStatus(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:270)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$3.doPerform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:100)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase$JmxOperation.perform(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:243)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.doStartDeployWithUndeploy(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:107)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.startDeploy(JavaeeJmxAdminServerBase.java:74)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminServerBase.startDeploy(TomcatAdminServerBase.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.startDeploy(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.remoteServer.agent.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler.a(ThreadInvocationHandler.java:56)
    at com.intellij.remoteServer.agent.impl.ThreadInvocationHandler.a(ThreadInvocationHandler.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: <redacted>/build/libs/exploded/myproject.war not found for the web module.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.addApplicationContext(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:217)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl$4.doPerform(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:121)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.admin.TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl$DeployStep.perform(TomcatAdminLocalServerImpl.java:274)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: 1. This looks like a strange path for an exploded archive. Is it realy exploded?
2. Please check in you project settings -> artifacts all the output directories.

Comment: That is actually the path defined for that artifact. I'm not sure why it chooses to use a directory with `.war` in the name, but it generates all of those artifacts when importing the project from Gradle. If I have a clean build the libs directory will be empty and IntelliJ fails to even create the `exploded` directory.

Comment: Checkout you `~/IntelliJIdea2017.2/system/log/idea.log` for more information.

Comment: It just gives the full stacktrace for the errors I was getting during deployment, but not really very much additional information. *(see updated question)*

Comment: May be this has something to do with that [idea does not share the gradle build dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174989/building-with-intellij-2017-2-out-directory-duplicates-files-in-build-director).

What Idea version and gradle are you using?

Comment: Currently using Gradle 3.5, and IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.2.

Comment: It seems that is has to be something specific to my development machine causing the problem. My coworkers are able to checkout the same project and use the shared run configurations to deploy the application. Which is what makes this problem really strange to me.

Answer (score 33):

**Before Intellij 2019.2 :**

Under Gradle Settings, you have to make sure you don't have checked `'Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle'`

[image]

**Since Intellij 2019.2 :**

Settings is now under '**Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle**'.
You have to select *Build and run using* : `Intellij IDEA`

An [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176700) has been opened on jetbrains bug tracker.

Comment: There is no option for *Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle* in 2019.2, what should be done for this version to fix it?

Comment: @Erlan I edited my answer according to changes in 2019.2

Comment: I also found that the exploded war output was not built correctly with the same exclusions until I chose the option 'User Gradle from' 'wrapper task in Gradle build script' in IntelliJ. This was affecting Tomcat logging since we needed to exclude logback from overriding all our log4j settings.