# Deploy two WARs with IntelliJ idea to tomcat

Tags: gradle, tomcat, intellij-idea

We have recently migrated from maven to gradle and since the migration we are experiencing following issue with deployment.

Our war-related part of gradle.kts looks as follows:

```kotlin
tasks.war {}
// Register named war for local development so IntelliJ Idea correctly creates deployable artifacts.
tasks.register<War>(project.name)
```

We can easily deploy created artifacts and access their endpoints on their host:port.

However, once we deploy secondary artifact (on different port), suddenly the first deployed service fails with following error:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.38/libexec/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.32.Final.jar
```

The full stack trace is here: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/25711ccd79556f346e605bb652606cfd

I guess there is some misconfiguration, but I haven't found anything related to it.

Only difference from Maven is that now we are using the "non-exploded" artifacts as I didn't manage to build them properly with gradle.

Comment: Solved with using exploded WARs as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523230/922584.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole issue seems to be caused by the usage of non-exploded WAR.

Solved with using exploded WARs as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523230/922584.