# Gradle Idea Plugin Respect Gradle Configuration

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

The simple question;

> Is there a way to make Intellij respect gradle configuration?

The details;

I created a new `sourceSets` called `integrationTest`

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest{
        java.srcDir 'src/integration/java'
        resources.srcDir 'src/integration/resources'
    }
}
```

I added the new source set to Intellij `testSourceDirs`

```
idea {
    module {
        testSourceDirs += file('src/integration/java')
    }
}
```

Everything works fine from Gradle perspective locally and on CI.

Now I don't want Intellij to create `out` directory which duplicates `build` dir I want Intellij to respect and follow gradle configuration as follows:

1. Source directory `main/java` should be compiled to `classes/java/main`
2. Source directory `test/java` should be compiled to `classes/java/test`
3. Source directory `integrationTest/java` should be compiled to `classes/java/integrationTest`
4. Resource directory `main/resources` should be compiled to `resources/main`
5. Resource directory `test/resources` should be compiled to `resources/test`
6. Resource directory `integrationTest/resources` should be compiled to `resources/integrationTest

The only solution I found so for ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46035904/440415)) is to have

1. All source directories (in my case I have only one at `main/java`) and resource directories goes to `classes/java/main`.
2. All test directories (in my case I have two at `test/java` and `integrationTest/java`) and resource direcotries (in my case I have two at `test/resources` and `integrationTest/resources`) goes to `classes/java/test`; and this is so wrong I need now to pay attention to file names and location not to override each other.

Gradle Version: `4.5`

Intellij Version: `2017.3`

---

**Update Jan 2021** This is not relevant anymore. It is working fine with newer Intellij. I personally tested with latest version `2020.3.2` Community edition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46035904/104891

Comment: @CrazyCoder your answer is linked in my question. it is valid but it isn't what I am asking for :-D