# out directory in IntelliJ project

Tags: intellij-idea, build

[Building with Intellij 2017.2 /out directory duplicates files in /build directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174989/building-with-intellij-2017-2-out-directory-duplicates-files-in-build-director) addresses this issue for Gradle-based projects. However, my project is Python and JavaScript with no Gradle in sight. Does IntelliJ now create this `out` directory for all projects no matter what build tools the projects are configured to use?

Answer (score 3):

`out` is the default name IntelliJ IDEA uses for the compiler output directory. When the project is configured via a build tool like Gradle or Maven, IDEA will change the compile output directory to match that used by those tools, such as `target` or `build`. However, it may not necessarily do this for all build tools. It'll depend on the level of support IDEA provides for a particular build tool. You can manually modify the output directory used in Project Structure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>). There is a project wide setting in *Project Settings > Project* and then a setting for each module in *Project Settings > Modules > "Paths" tab*.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with IntelliJ 2021.1. In my case the Project Settings > Modules > Paths was correctly set, yet it still duplicated everything from the `\target` to `\out`.  In addition to that it could also not detect any of my Unit Tests even when I right-click directly on the Unit Test.

What did work for me was that I had to close IntelliJ and manually delete the `.idea` directory and re-import the entire project.

Comment: Do you know if you had "Build Tools -> Gradle -> build and run" set to IDEA instead of Gradle?  This seems to cause the out to be generated

Comment: Thanks. This  helped me. I tried Javaru's answer, but the settings kept getting flipped back. I guess there was a file somewhere in .idea that wouldn't update.