# Building Spring framework: Why is IntelliJ complaining about errors but editor seems to be able to find classes?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, build

I'm following the [guide to build spring-framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Build-from-Source) ([including the guide to import into IDEA](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/import-into-idea.md)) with the hopes of building & contributing a patch to spring.

I'm able to build & test the `spring-core` module but I'm failing to build the `spring-context` module because IntelliJ isn't able to find certain symbols. But if I navigate to the source of the error then everything looks good. I can even `cmd + click` into the specific classes it's complaining about.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Can you build it from command line by Gradle? Do you use Delegate run/build actions to Gradle option in IDE?

Comment: yes, building from command line works perfectly. I don't know what "Delegate run/build actions" are; but I'll get back to you after I find out.

Comment: It is described in this blog post http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2016/11/gradle-goodness-delegate-build-and-run.html

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be related to [out-directory-duplicates-files-in-build-director](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174989/building-with-intellij-2017-2-out-directory-duplicates-files-in-build-director).

Since that problem, I prefer to delegate the build to gradle - see
[gradle godness delegate build and run](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2016/11/gradle-goodness-delegate-build-and-run.html)

Make sure to use the latest Intellij Idea version. There has been a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189463) regarding the 'delegate build and run to gradle' feature.