# How to get Spring Boot's Automatic Restart working in IntelliJ IDEA Community? (out/build directory problem)

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm working on a Gradle-based Spring Boot 2 project in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 Community.

I'd like to get Spring Boot's **automatic restart** working, so that when I edit a file in the IDE, the IDE recompiles it on the fly (without delegating it to Gradle), the running Spring Boot instance sees the updated class file and restarts part of the application.

I have:

1. Added `spring-boot-devtools` to my project's dependencies
2. Enabled "Build Project Automatically" in Settings / Build-Execution-Deployment / Compiler
3. Enabled `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running` in the Registry

But I still cannot get the automatic restart to work.

The problem seems to be that IDEA places compiled classes in an **out** directory instead of Gradle's **build** directory. Moreover, the compiled classes (and updated resource files) are placed in a different sub-directory structure than Gradle's. This is apparently a [well-known "feature" of IDEA, as in "Works As Intended."](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175172)

```
out/
  production/             <- different
    classes/
      (package)/
        MyClass.class
  resources/
    templates/
      test.html

build/
  classes/
    kotlin/               <- different
      main/               <- different
        (package)/
          MyClass.class
  resources/
    main/                 <- different
      templates/
        test.html
```

So, taking into account this "feature" of IDEA, how can I get Spring Boot's automatic restart / live reload to work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46035904/104891

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes, I saw that discussion. Here I'm specifically asking if anybody knows a way to make Automatic Restart work. I tried a few of the options listed there, to no avail.

Comment: You've tried that solution and the build directory didn't change? Or it changed, but it still doesn't restart? If the latter, your question title is misleading.

Comment: @CrazyCoder That solution is wrong or incomplete. First of all, by applying those directives, IDEA puts the output files into `build/classes/main/(package)/MyClass.class` and `build/classes/main/templates/test.html` which are still different from what Gradle expects (`build/classes/kotlin/main/(package)/MyClass.class` and `build/resources/main/templates/test.html`) Second, by changing those `sourceSets`, Spring Boot does not work anymore: "Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved." So it's quite far from a working solution. If you can fix it, please post it below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I needed to start the Spring Boot application without using Gradle.

Click on the dropdown menu on the upper right corner; Edit Configurations; click on the plus icon on the top left corner; choose Kotlin (or Java, whatever your main language is for the Spring Boot project); enter the Main class, which is the class containing the `main()` method (for Kotlin, enter the name of the file with a `Kt` suffix, for example `com/demo/myblog/Application.kt` becomes `com.demo.myblog.ApplicationKt`) then OK; and use that as a start target.

Incremental compilation is configured as in the question above.