# intellij gradle based project unwanted output in bin/ dir

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a gradle based kotlin/java project using intellij IDEA for development.

As the project is gradle based all build artefacts are under gradles build/ directory|folder.

But there are also all `.kt` and `.class` files under `<projectRoot>/bin`

Does Intellij need to have these there?

I could not find anything in the project neither in intellij settings, nor did google searches enlighten me on this.

how to tell Intellij to work with the gradle build artefacts files under `build/` and ***not*** to produce files under `bin/` dir ???

Comment: Please share any sample project that would illustrate the problem ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46035904/104891. Make sure the [build is performed by Gradle](https://i.imgur.com/AmWjMZR.png).

Comment: No, it's not a bot comment. I'm IntelliJ IDEA technical support team lead kindly requesting more details in order to help with your problem as I was not able to reproduce it with the Gradle projects I have. IntelliJ IDEA doesn't create `bin` directory for me, hence the questions. Sorry if it was not clear. It's possible that build output directory is overridden in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: * The reply above was provided to [this comment](https://i.imgur.com/DP35owd.png) from Dirk that he has removed later: "is this a bot comment?? question is: why is there anything at all (???) under bin/ dir if I have a gradle project that I imported to intellij".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the project in eclipse now and then ... and Eclipse compiled to `bin/`.

So it wasn't Intellij at all ...

I apologise for the inconveniences